# What are the most important parts of the .NET framework for a beginner?

Tags: .net

You often see, on sites like [The Daily WTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daily_WTF), examples of overengineered code that should have just been a call to a built-in method within the .NET framework.

What namespaces/classes should be considered essential knowledge for a developer starting his/her first .NET job?

*As per Joel Spolsky's instruction for these types of questions, please limit your answers to individual items for voting purposes.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
System;
System.Collections;
System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: I'd like to add System.Text.RegularExpressions as well.

Comment: Not System.Collections though, eeee-vil weakly typed collections....

Comment: RegularExpressions for absolute beginner? Yeah right...

Answer (score 10):

System.IO is very important.

Understanding how Streams and the various implementations work (FileStream, MemoryStream, CompressionStream) when combined with binary data or text from a TextReader/TextWriter instance is an essential skill.

Comment: The streams are an essential part to understand. However its not the most intuitive (and in my opinion one of the worst designed bits of the framework)

Answer (score 7):

```
System.IDisposable
```

Not properly disposing objects that implement it (streams, database connections, sockets, etc) leads to locked file errors, open database connections and a whole lot of other unpleasant and hard to find bugs in your software.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idispose.aspx

Comment: Dispose is clearly not a beginner issue in my opinion.

Comment: Just because new and "experienced" high level developers do now know how important it is to manage resources you should not ignore it as a beginner.

Comment: Knowing how to implement IDisposable isn't for beginners but knowing that it exists and that you should dispose of objects that implement it is.

Answer (score 7):

System.Brains and System.CommonSense

Answer (score 6):

using System;

System is probably the most important namespace as it contains the core features such as  Object and Array as well as the GC (Garbage Collector).

Answer (score 4):

System.String

and learn how to use regular expressions that are exposed via the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace.

This will save you a huge amount of time if you end up re-writing text parsers or other string related tasks that have built in functions for them already.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

And the daily WTF is awesome :D

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in VB.NET I'd say the My namespace is very important.  It contains shortcuts to a lot of areas of the framework that used to be spread all over the place in the framework.  It's also quite intuitive.  You can write things like:
For Each Printer in My.Computer.Printers
or
My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenFile(Filename)
My.Computer.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory
My.Computer.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea

Comment: Yeah, and a great way not to be able to transition to C# when needed :) Really, I would suggest avoiding the My namespace unless working alone. Oh, and in BCL it's System.IO.File.Open(FileName) - it's even shorter :D

Comment: Yep agreed I would avoid My namespace

Comment: While not explicitly stated in the question (I'm debating changing it now), my intent is to learn C# first so the My namespace, while useful to many, isn't useful to me. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

System.Data, particularly Datatable,

Answer (score 0):

You should thoroughly look over this application.  It contains many patterns and best practices that you should follow.

[patterns & practices Guidance Explorer](http://www.codeplex.com/guidanceExplorer)

Answer (score 0):

- System.IO for file operations
- System.Collections & System.Collections.Generic - learn how to manipulate / use Lists, Dictionary, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some line to be drawn between a Windows Developer and a Web Developer, where either can be using the .NET Framework.  System.Web is very useful if you are doing Web Development as well as knowing how .NET interacts with [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services), while this may be irrelevant for a Developer who does Windows and Console Applications.

These are starting to blur at times so a developer should try to see where they want to be in the stack, e.g. do they want to do it all like in a small business environment or focus mainly on development like bigger shops can do.